# Failing to open Excel files for writing

Tags: perl, xls

I am using `open` to write data into an Excel file. This is working fine with .txt files, but with .xls files it always fails.

This is the code I am writing

```
$filename = "abc.xls";
$fhandle  = "ABC";

open( $fhandle, ">$filename" ) || die "cannot open file $filename";
```

The same code executes fine in another environment which has an older Perl version.

I need help on how can I fix this.

Comment: Include `$!` in the [die](http://p3rl.org/die) message and copy it here. Also, read again the documentation of [open](http://p3rl.org/open) - why do you set handle to ABC before opening the file?

Comment: Just write in the `csv` output format with a `tab` delimit and then open in excel you can.

Comment: I assure you this is nothing to do with the version of Perl. I would guess that the problem is a privilege violation, either because another program already has the file open, or because you don't have write access to the file or directory. You can prove this for yourself by setting `$filename` to a path to an .xls file that doesn't exist in a folder where you have been able to open a .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem to the issue. The environment I was trying to create these files in already had the files with the same name but did not have permissions for me to edit those files. I deleted the old files and it worked like a charm.

Thanks a lot for your help guys.!!

Shivam

Answer (score -1):

A file handle is a file handle. Not a string.

Also, you are typing the filename in the `open` call. Why don't you use the $filename variable you so neatly created two lines earlier?

I would try something like this:

`$filename = "abc.xls";
open($fhandle, ">$filename") || die "cannot open file $filename";`

Also, this xls file: Is it open in excel when you try to run the script? Excel will stop you from opening it in another application or script if you do.

Furthermore : Please use `strict` and `warnings`. They will make your life much better.